# $f_n$ doesn't converge pointwise for any $x\in [0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove/Disprove:

There exist a sequence of continuous functions $f_n:[0,1]\to[0,\infty)$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^1 f_n(x) dx=0$ but $f_n$ doesn't converge pointwise for any $x\in [0,1]$?

Edit:I guess it's false.
Since, $\int_{0}^1 f_n(x) dx=f_n(c_n)$ for some $c_n\in (0,1)$.
Now, $[0,1]$ being compact it has a convergent subsequence, let it converges to $d$, so i guess $f_n(d)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$

Comment: What are your thoughts on this so far?

Comment: Hint: the answer turns out to be the same if you drop the assumption of continuity. It's a little bit easier to think through what's happening if you deal with piecewise constant functions.

Comment: @Clement C.,i edited

Comment: Your argument has a flaw: it doesn't show that $f_n(d) \to 0$, you show that there is a subsequence $(\phi(n))_n$ such that $f_{\phi(n)}(c_{\phi(n)})\to 0$. (The statement is actually true. Follow @Ian's hint, maybe think of a "small interval" that keeps shrinking and moving in $[0,1]$, and $f_n$ is the indicator of that interval...)

Comment: $f_n(x)= \sin(2\pi x+n)$

Comment: Wrong! $f_n$ is non-nengative.

Comment: @Clement $f_n$ has to be continuous.

Comment: It can be made continuous easily once you have the idea. Replace intervals indicators ("rectangles") by triangles, for instance. @who

Answer (score 1):

For $2^k\leqslant n< 2^{k+1}$ let $f_n = \mathsf 1_{[2^{-k}(n-2^k),\ 2^{-k}(n-2^k+1)}]$, $k=0,1,\ldots$. Then
$$
\int_0^1 f_n(x)\ \mathsf dx = 2^{-k}\mathsf 1_{[2^k,2^{k+1})}(n)\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow 0
$$
but for any $x\in[0,1]$, there are infinitely many $n$ such that $f_n(x)=1$ and infinitely many $n$ such that $f_n(x)=0$, so $f_n$ does not converge a.e.

Comment: Good idea, but your $f_n$ isn't continuous.

Comment: You can replace the "rectangles" with "triangles" to make the functions continuous. Same idea, just notationally more cumbersome.